# How to adjust the color of the folders in Finder in Yosemite?

Tags: finder, macos, color

After upgrading to Yosemite, the color of the folders in Finder changes from a nice soothing blue to some brighter blue that has much higher contrast.

I am curious that is there any way to change that back? Like creating some user defined css file.

There is a dark mode for the system wide menu, is there a dark mode for the Finder?

Comment: How to do it yourself: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/152187/4552

Answer (score 2):

Panic (panic.com) had a utility called CandyBar that let you change most of the default icons on MacOS.

Actually this was taken over by the Icon Factory (iconfactory.com)

It **may** still work but look at their site first. They admit it won't change dock idons, so don't even try that. If it does work on Yosemite you can change the **default** icons for a variety of things. Meaning if you change the default icon any newly created icons inherit the custom appearance.

Barring that you can copy an icon file that you like:

--get info on the folder
--click on the icon
--copy (CMD-C)

Then repeat that, replacing step three with "Paste (CMD-V)" on any icon you want to change. Only problem here is that it only changes one folder icon. So you gotta do that for every folder icon you don't like. On the up side it is fully supported by Apple and works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

For Yosemite use the app LiteIcon. You can take the folder icons from a Mavericks install /System/Libray/Core Services/CoreTypes/

(I also went back to Lucida Grande as the system font)

Answer (score 1):

[LiteIcon](http://www.freemacsoft.net/liteicon/) is the best option for changing application icons and system icons for OS X Yosemite. It has a simple interface and is quite intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

@Georgia - That was a great tip .. but the folder locale got slightly lost in translation .. here is what I did

PROPER PATH

$ cd /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/

The Resources folder contains all the icons. Using "ditto" so it copies resources properly. The "-ck" makes a zipped archive.

$ ditto -ck Resources mav-icons.zip

Just copy off to the Yosemite machine, and drag .icns onto the appropriate locations in LiteIcon. Shame on Apple for not making this a simple option.

Answer (score 1):

LiteIcon looks great, but it cannot change the system icons since El Capitan/10.11 - something to do with System Integrity Protection

[http://freemacsoft.net/liteicon/sip.html]

The workaround (disable protection, reboot, run app, enable protection, reboot) seemed a bit risky to me (security-wise), so I:

1. Booted my Mac from an old 10.7.5 external recovery disk
2. Found the relevant files, and replaced them manually.

Here is the script that I used to do this manipulation. It depended on a few sets of icons I had already downloaded.

```
SYSTEM=/Volumes/MacOSX/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources

cd    $SYSTEM
mkdir BAD
mv ApplicationsFolderIcon.icns  BAD
mv BurnableFolderIcon.icns  BAD
mv DesktopFolderIcon.icns   BAD
mv DeveloperFolderIcon.icns BAD
mv DocumentsFolderIcon.icns BAD
mv DownloadsFolder.icns BAD
mv GenericFolderIcon.icns   BAD
mv GroupFolder.icns     BAD
mv LibraryFolderIcon.icns   BAD
mv MovieFolderIcon.icns     BAD
mv MusicFolderIcon.icns     BAD
mv OpenFolderIcon.icns      BAD
mv PicturesFolderIcon.icns  BAD
mv PublicFolderIcon.icns    BAD
mv ServerApplicationsFolderIcon.icns    BAD
mv SitesFolderIcon.icns     BAD
mv SmartFolderIcon.icns     BAD
mv SystemFolderIcon.icns    BAD
mv UsersFolderIcon.icns     BAD
mv UtilitiesFolder.icns     BAD

#
# Downloaded some icons from:
# http://yosemiteicons.deviantart.com/gallery/52150606/Folder-Sets
#
# Sadly, some of them don't have replacements:
#
cd  /Volumes/MacOSX/Users/nigel/Downloads
cp -pr "./Flader Transparency Original/Applications/Applications.icns" $SYSTEM/ApplicationsFolderIcon.icns
cp -pr $SYSTEM/BAD/BurnableFolderIcon.icns  $SYSTEM
cp -pr "./Flader Transparency Original/Desktop/Desktop.icns"        $SYSTEM/DesktopFolderIcon.icns
cp -pr $SYSTEM/BAD/DeveloperFolderIcon.icns $SYSTEM
cp -pr "./Flader Transparency Original/Documents/Documents.icns"    $SYSTEM/DocumentsFolderIcon.icns
cp -pr "./Flader Transparency Original/Downloads/Downloads.icns"    $SYSTEM/DownloadsFolder.icns
cp -pr "./Flader original/Generic/Generic.icns"             $SYSTEM/GenericFolderIcon.icns
cp -pr $SYSTEM/BAD/GroupFolder.icns     $SYSTEM
cp -pr "./Flader default  part2/icns/Library.icns"          $SYSTEM/LibraryFolderIcon.icns
cp -pr $SYSTEM/BAD/MovieFolderIcon.icns     $SYSTEM
cp -pr "./Flader Transparency Original/Music/Music.icns"        $SYSTEM/MusicFolderIcon.icns
cp -pr $SYSTEM/BAD/OpenFolderIcon.icns      $SYSTEM
cp -pr "./Flader Transparency Original/Pictures/Pictures.icns"      $SYSTEM/PicturesFolderIcon.icns
cp -pr "./Flader Transparency Original/Public/Public.icns"      $SYSTEM/PublicFolderIcon.icns
cp -pr $SYSTEM/BAD/ServerApplicationsFolderIcon.icns    $SYSTEM
cp -pr $SYSTEM/BAD/SitesFolderIcon.icns     $SYSTEM
cp -pr $SYSTEM/BAD/SmartFolderIcon.icns     $SYSTEM
cp -pr "./Flader default  part2/icns/System.icns"           $SYSTEM/SystemFolderIcon.icns
cp -pr "./Flader default  part2/icns/User.icns"             $SYSTEM/UsersFolderIcon.icns
cp -pr "./Flader default  part2/icns/Utilities.icns"            $SYSTEM/UtilitiesFolder.icns
```

A few commands might also be necessary, to refresh the icons, after booting back off your 10.11 or 10.12 disk

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} ;
sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
killall Dock
killall Finder
```